# Quando usar Supertipo ou Subtipo no retorno do método?

Tags: java, tipagem, return, polimorfismo

Suponha que eu tenha um método chamado "`meuMetodo()`" que retorna um Objeto do Tipo `ArrayList<String>`, eu posso fazer este método declarar que retorna Tipos mais Concretos ou mais Abstratos:

> - `public ArrayList<String> meuMetodo() {...}`
> - `public List<String> meuMetodo() {...}`
> - `public Collection<String> meuMetodo() {...}`
> - `public Object meuMetodo() {...}`

- Existe alguma convenção de "boa prática" sobre qual Tipo declarar como retorno para cada *contexto*?
- Quais as vantagens, as desvantagens e as limitações de declarar como retorno um Tipo mais Abstrato? *(como List, Collection, ou até mesmo Object)*
- Quais as vantagens, as desvantagens e as limitações de declarar como retorno um Tipo mais Concreto? *(neste exemplo, o mais concreto seria o ArrayList)*

Desejo uma resposta canônica, que leve em consideração coisas como:

- Faz diferença se o método em questão será sobrescrito por uma Subclasse futuramente (eu perco flexibilidade ao **estender** dependendo do que eu declarar como Tipo de retorno)?
- É importante considerar o que os Clientes deste método (os códigos que o chamarão) necessitam do Objeto retornado (por exemplo, os métodos que eles irão chamar no Objeto retornado)?
- É importante considerar para quais métodos o Objeto retornado será enviado como argumento?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> - Faz diferença se o método em questão será sobrescrito por uma    Subclasse futuramente (eu perco flexibilidade ao estender dependendo
>   do que eu declarar como Tipo de retorno)?

Sim. Faz diferença. Imagine que você tenha o supertipo:

```
public interface MySupertype{
  List<String> myMethod()
}
```

nos seus subtipos você pode retornar diferentes implementações de List que o seu código vai funcionar:

```
class ArraySubType implements MySupertype{
  public List<String> myMethod(){
    return new ArrayList<String>();
  }
}

class LinkedListSubType implements MySupertype{
  public List<String> myMethod(){
    return new LinkedList<String>();
  }
}
```

do contrário, se você declara um tipo concreto no supertipo, você perde flexibilidade, pois você está forçando os subtipos a usarem uma implementação específica do seu tipo de retorno.

> - É importante considerar o que os Clientes deste método (os códigos que o chamarão) necessitam do Objeto retornado (por exemplo, os métodos que eles irão chamar no Objeto retornado)?
> - É importante considerar para quais métodos o Objeto retornado será    enviado como argumento?

De maneira geral sim. Se os clientes do seu tipo/método precisarem fazer muitos casts ou ficar encapsulando o objeto retornado em adapters, isso é um indício de que o tipo foi mal projetado. Por outro lado, deve-se levar em consideração que um tipo com muitos métodos, que atenda muitos clientes pode estar violando o [ISP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) (princípio da segregação de interfaces).

Resumindo: ao declarar um método em um tipo, principalmente interfaces e classes abstratas, tanto para parâmetros como objetos de retorno, você deve utilizar o tipo que seja o mais abstrato possível, mas que tenha os métodos necessários para manipular o objeto ou que não te obrigue a realizar um cast. Isso se chama "programar para a interface, e não para a implementação".