# criar objetos de forma dinâmica

Tags: java, design-pattern, engenharia-de-software

Estou com um problema na faculdade em engenharia de software que é o seguinte:
Tenho o seguinte esquema ao efetuar o pagamento de um carrinho de compras devo saber se é BOLETO ou CARTÃO_DE_CREDITO. Caso seja boleto eu gero um numero aleatório representando o código de barras, caso seja cartão de crédito eu recebo o numero do cartão e a quantidade de parcelas que o cliente desejar e calcular o valor de cada prestação (nesse caso o numero do cartão é alegórico).

Pensei em algo assim:

Pagamento.java

```
public interface Pagamento {

}
```

PagamentoBoleto.java

```
import java.util.Random;

public class PagamentoBoleto implements Pagamento{

    private final int codigoDeBarra;

    public PagamentoBoleto(final double valorCompra){
        this.codigoDeBarra = gerarCodigoDeBarra(valorCompra);
    }

    private int gerarCodigoDeBarra(final double valorCompra){
        long milisigundosAgora = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long semente = (long) (valorCompra + milisigundosAgora);

        Random random = new Random(semente);

        int min = 1000;
        int max = 9999;

        return random.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
    }
}
```

PagamentoCartaoCredito.java

```
public class PagamentoCartaoCredito implements Pagamento{

    private final String numeroCartaoCredito;
    private final int quantidadeParcelas;

    public PagamentoCartaoCredito(final String numeroCartaoCredito, final int quantidadeParcelas){
        this.numeroCartaoCredito = numeroCartaoCredito;
        this.quantidadeParcelas = quantidadeParcelas;
    }

    public double getValorParcela(double valorCompra) {
        return valorCompra / quantidadeParcelas;
    }
}
```

TipoPagamentoEnumFactory.java

```
public enum TipoPagamento {


 CARTAO(1) {
        public Pagamento getTipoPagamento() {
            return new PagamentoCartaoCredito();
        }
    },
    BOLETO(1) {
        public Pagamento getTipoPagamento() {
            return new PagamentoBoleto();
        }
    };

    public int op;

    TipoPagamento(int valor) {
        op = valor;
    }
    public abstract Pagamento getTipoPagamento();
}
```

Problema .... como as formas de pagamentos tem construtores distintos não sei como instância-los de forma bem dinâmica e flexível.

Answer (score 5):

## Objetivo

Entendo que o objetivo da pergunta seria como projetar uma API de modo a facilitar extensão e manutenção.

## Princípios e ressalvas

Uma boa abordagem seria adotar princípios SOLID. Porém já foi ponderado na [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/278234/criar-objetos-de-forma-din%C3%A2mica/281385#answer-279079) do @Douglas, tais princípios devem ser aplicados quando fazem sentido, evitando *over-engineering* e *otimização precoce*.

Por exemplo, num projeto de curto prazo com um ou dois desenvolvedores é fácil passar por cima disso.

Por outro lado, se há perspectiva de investimento a médio ou longo prazo, se há outras pessoas do projeto ou até de outros projetos que vão consumir sua API sem saber de todos os detalhes de como ela funciona, então faz todo sentido e torna-se até necessário investir um tempo a mais para projetar algo robusto.

Fred Brooks, no *The Mythical Man-Month*, estima que desenvolver software para reuso requer três vezes mais esforço.

## Construindo uma API robusta

Vamos a um exemplo que fica no meio entre acadêmico e "de mercado":

> Construa uma API que suporte por padrão pagamentos via boleto e cartão e também permita novos meios de pagamento sem modificar as classes existentes.
>
> Essa API é integrada com uma loja online, que possui o seguinte fluxo:
>
> 1. Ao fechar a compra, o Usuário seleciona o tipo de pagamento
> 2. O Sistema tenta efetuar o pagamento e verifica o resultado
>
>    1. Se bem sucedido, o sistema registra o pagamento como efetuado
>    2. Se for necessário aguardar confirmação (como no caso de boleto), o sistema agenda uma outra tentativa de efetuar o pagamento para o outro dia.
>    3. Se for mal sucedido, o sistema envia uma mensagem para o usuário

### Interfaces e classes básicas

```
public enum Status {
    ERRO, SUCESSO, AGUARDANDO_CONFIRMACAO
}

public class Resultado {
    Status status;
    String motivo;
}

public interface MetodoPagamento {
    Resultado efetuar(Compra compra);
}
```

### `Pagamento`, a classe principal

O sistema da loja então poderia implementar um serviço de pagamentos assim:

```
@Named
public class PagamentoService {
    @Inject
    PagamentoDao pagamentoDao;
    @Inject
    AgendamentoService agendamentoService;
    @Inject
    ErroPagamentoService erroPagamentoService;

    // código que pode ser mais ou menos complexo dependendo 
    // de quantas integrações forem necessárias
    Status efetuar(String usuario, MetodoPagamento metodo, Compra compra) {
        Resultado r = metodo.efetuar(compra);
        if (Status.ERRO == r.status) {
            log.error("Erro...");
            erroPagamentoService.notificarErroPagamento(usuario, compra, r.motivo);
        } else if (Status.AGUARDANDO_CONFIRMACAO == r.status) {
            log.info("Tenta novamente amanhã...");
            agendamentoService.agendarVerificacaoPagamento(
               usuario, metodo, compra);
        } else {
            log.info("Sucesso...");
            pagamentoDao.inserir(usuario, compra);
        }
        return r;
    }
}
```

### Pagando com boletos

```
public class PagamentoBoleto implements MetodoPagamento {   
    public Resultado efetuar(Compra compra) {
        int codigoDeBarras = CodigoDeBarras.gerar(compra);

        boolean pagamentoDetectado = apiBanco.codigoDeBarrasFoiPago(codigoDeBarras);
        if (pagamentoDetectado) {
            return new Resultado(Status.SUCESSO, "");        
        } 
        return new Resultado(Status.AGUARDANDO_CONFIRMACAO, "Pagamento não detectado junto ao banco");        
    }
}
```

### Pagando com cartão

```
public class PagamentoCartao implements MetodoPagamento {   
    private DadosCartao cartao;

    public PagamentoCartao(DadosCartao cartao) {
        this.cartao = cartao;
    }

    public Resultado efetuar(Compra compra) {
        int numeroTransacao = CartaoCredito.gerarNumeroTransacao(compra);

        boolean conseguiuPagar = apiBanco.pagarComCartao(cartao, compra);
        if (conseguiuPagar) {
            return new Resultado(Status.SUCESSO, "Transação " + numeroTransacao + " efetuada com sucesso");        
        } 
        return new Resultado(Status.ERRO, "Banco rejeitou cartão " + cartao);        
    }
}
```

## Controlando tudo isso

Em algum lugar do código (no caso de um sistema web, possivelmente um controlador ou endpoint), vai haver uma código que lista os tipos de pagamento e instancia o respetivo método de pagamento.

Exemplo:

```
@POST("/pagar")
@Named
class PagamentoResource {
    @Inject PagamentoService pagamentoService;

    @POST("cartao")
    public Response pagarComCartao(FormPagamentoCartao form) { 
        DadosCartao cartao = createDadosCartao(form);
        MetodoPagamento metodo = new PagamentoCartao(cartao);
        Copra compra = recuperarCompraDaSessao();
        return pagar(metodo, compra);        
    }

    @POST("boleto")
    public Response pagarComBoleto(FormPagamentoBoleto form) { 
        DadosCartao cartao = createDadosCartao(form);
        MetodoPagamento metodo = new PagamentoCartao(cartao);
        Copra compra = recuperarCompraDaSessao();
        return pagar(metodo, compra);        
    }

    private Response pagar(MetodoPagamento metodo, Compra compra) { 
        Copra compra = recuperarCompraDaSessao();
        String usuario = recuperarUsuarioLogado();
        Resultado r = pagamentoService.efetuar(usuario, metodo, compra);
        if (Status.SUCESSO == r.status) {
            return Response.ok();
        }
        return createErrorResponse(r.motivo);        
    }
}
```

Obviamente, a interface do usuário também deverá refletir as opções disponíveis. Por exemplo, no caso do cartão, um formulário com os detalhes do cartão é exibido e no caso do boleto apenas uma imagem ou PDF, mas ambos não fazem parte do pagamento em si, portanto não incluídas nos exemplos.

## *Auto-discover* or *do not auto-discover*, eis a questão

Existe algo que confunde um pouco os desenvolvedores quando se fala em princípios SOLID, tal como o de não alterar as classes existentes quando se adiciona um novo código, levando aqueles que conhecem um pouco mais da linguagem a logo pensar em usar reflexão para descobrir classes em tempo de execução.

Embora algumas bibliotecas ou frameworks cheguem a este nível, a interpretação mais comum não é que ***nenhuma*** classe existente deva ser modificada, mas sim uma ***quantidade mínima*** de classes, preferencialmente um único ponto do sistema que controla a funcionalidade em questão.

Um bom teste para saber se o desenvolvedor está aplicando devidamente padrões e princípios corretamente numa base de código é contar quantos pontos do sistema são afetados por uma mudança pontual. Quanto menos, melhor.

Agora, você já trabalhou em um sistema no qual, para adicionar algo mesmo que trivial você precisa mexer em múltiplas classes de todas as camadas da aplicação? E ainda por cima você nunca tem a garantia que não esqueceu de algum ponto? Isto é comum quando, ao invés de abstrair conceitos em interfaces e classes bem projetadas, sem perceber o programador repete a mesma lógica ou diferentes aspectos da mesma lógica em diferentes pontos do sistema (ainda que o código seja diferente, o que é pior ainda).

### Adicionando um novo método de pagamento

Sem tocar no código, vou apenas listar o que seria necessário modificar para adicionar um pagamento, por exemplo, via PayPal:

1. Outra implementação `PagamentoPaypal`.
2. Novo endpoint (novo método na classe *resource*)
3. UI relativa ao método de pagamento

### Automatizando ao extremo

Suponha que estamos desenvolvendo um ERP plugável e queremos permitir novos métodos de pagamento sem modificar o núcleo.

Aí então podería-se pensar em usar reflexão para listar as classes no *classpath*, OSGi ou alguma outra tecnologia.

Na parte do ERP, teríamos que modificar:

- Criar uma classe para localizar plugins. O plugin deve seguir um formato estabelecido e fornecer as partes necessárias para a interface, validação e efetuação do pagamento.
- UI deve fazer o lookup por todos os métodos de pagamento e listá-los.
- UI deve conseguir inserir formulários de pagamento fornecidos pelos plugins.
- O ERP deve permitir ao plugin adicionar um novo endpoint que faça validação e chame o pagamento. Existem muitas formas de se fazer isso, mas para este exemplo suponha que o plugin pode fornecer uma nova classe *resource* com um endpoint qualquer.

Ainda neste caso, um desenvolvedor querendo plugar um novo método deveria:

1. Implementar novo `MetodoPagamentoPaypal`
2. Implementar endpoint numa nova classe *resource*
3. Fornecer UI com formulário respectivo ao tipo de pagamento

## Conclusões

- "Fechado para modificação" não significa que nenhum classe do sistema precisa ser modificada, mas o mínimo possível ou razoável.
- Ambas as formas propostas para adicionar um novo pagamento requerem exatamente três adições ou modificações: método de pagamento, endpoint, UI.
- A proposta "plugável", embora não modifique as classes existentes para adicionar novos métodos de pagamento, adiciona complexidade e requer praticamente o mesmo esforço de implementação.

  - Portanto, ela não é superior em si mesma, mas a escolha de uma ou outra depende de quem consome a API, ou seja, se é alguém de dentro ou fora do projeto.

Comment: +1 Muito bom, só um detalhe, a classe `PagamentoResource` está com dois métodos `pagarComCartao`, acho que sua intenção era que o segundo método fosse `pagarComBoleto`.

Comment: Obrigado, @Douglas.

Answer (score 3):

Parece-me desnecessário um Enum para fazer isso, você pode simplesmente criar dois métodos que serão "factories" de `Pagamento`:

<sub>Obs.:[É melhor usar BigDecimal que double para valores monetários](https://www.devmedia.com.br/java-bigdecimal-trabalhando-com-mais-precisao/30286).</sub>

```
public class CriadorDePagamentos {

    public static Pagamento criarPagamento(final BigDecimal valorCompra) {
        return new PagamentoBoleto(valorCompra);
    }

    public static Pagamento criarPagamento(final BigDecimal valorCompra, final String numeroCartaoCredito, final int quantidadeParcelas) {
        return new PagamentoCartaoCredito(valorCompra, numeroCartaoCredito, quantidadeParcelas);
    }
}
```

E poderia ser usado assim:

```
Pagamento pg = CriadorDePagamentos.criarPagamento(valor);
```

ou assim:

```
Pagamento pg = CriadorDePagamentos.criarPagamento(valor, numCartao, qtdParcelas);
```

Note que, o código-cliente não precisa nem conhecer os tipos de pagamentos disponíveis, ficando altamente desacoplado.

Mas isto só faz sentido para o código-cliente se ele encontrar o que precisa dentro da interface que está recebendo, que no caso é `Pagamento`; dentro desta interface poderíamos ter, por exemplo, um método `getValorCompra()` que poderia ser sobrescrito sem problemas tanto por `PagamentoBoleto` quanto por `PagamentoCartaoCredito`, pois essas classes possuem um `valorCompra`.

A escolha dos métodos da interface é um assunto difícil que pode levar a diferentes modelagens da arquitetura, cada uma podendo ter seus prós e contras, sendo também necessário conhecer os códigos-clientes da interface para fazer-se escolhas sensatas, e sendo interessante considerar o [Princípio da Segregação de Interfaces](https://robsoncastilho.com.br/2013/04/14/principios-solid-principio-da-segregacao-de-interface-isp/). As escolhas podem trazer impactos como proliferação de `instaceof`, `Cast`, pode levar a criar-se operações na interface que podem ser inválidas dependendo da implementação dela (como o método [Collection#add(E e)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#add(E))), ou mesmo levar a [alteração no retorno dos métodos-factories para tipos mais concretos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/203731/quando-usar-supertipo-ou-subtipo-no-retorno-do-m%C3%A9todo), etc. Não é um assunto simples para ser abordado nesta resposta, mas é importante.

Comment: Sobre o código não precisar conhecer o tipo de pagamento, isso se torna útil quando tem algum método na interface. Enfim, a modelagem da interface creio que também deveria ser criticada

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado É verdade, mas me parece que só um `getValorCompra()` faria sentido na interface, **talvez** um set também (eu teria que analisar com cuidado se isso faria sentido, mas acho que não, pois ele até marcou como final as variáveis de instância, ele deve querer imutabilidade). Talvez o @Gabriel não colocou nada na interface para focar o exemplo no que importa a ele, ou por não saber ainda o que colocará nela. Vou editar minha resposta depois para falar sobre essa questão.

Comment: Além de não colocar os métodos da interface, o @GabrielLemos também não colocou o código que faz uso dessa interface. Acredito que isso também ajudaria a entender melhor a questão e a fornecer uma solução. A solução atual é boa e pragmática, mas note que ela viola o princípio aberto-fechado (um novo tipo de pagamento requer modificação da classe CriadorDePagamentos). É só um ponto, talvez isso não tenha importância em uma aplicação pequena (por isso que é importante também ser pragmático).

Comment: @Piovezan, sem utilizar reflexão eu não vejo como não ter uma classe aberta para edição na arquitetura, pois, ao criar uma nova classe que implementa a interface será necessário conectá-la à arquitetura de algum modo, ou seja, alguma classe aberta-para-edição vai ter que se acoplar a nova-classe para prover instâncias dela e/ou acesso a ela. Neste caso, é classe CriadorDePagamentos que fica aberta, e a ideia é que através dela as classes-clientes não fiquem abertas-para-edição. Meu intuito é evitar que várias classes clientes precisem ser editadas ao criar-se novos Tipos de Pagamento.

Comment: @Douglas Eu acredito que é possível sim. Cria-se uma classe e adiciona-se à arquitetura por meio de código novo, e não alterando código já escrito. Mas para visualizar uma solução nesse sentido seria preciso que o AP incluísse na pergunta o código-cliente, isto é, o que faz uso dos Pagamentos.

Comment: @Piovezan o códigos-clientes da interface realmente fazem falta, pois através disso saberíamos melhor o que deve haver na interface, e se seria necessário usar Segregação de Interfaces para atender diferentes códigos-clientes com diferentes necessidades sem acoplá-los às classes Concretas de Pagamento. Mas pelo que entendi, o foco da pergunta não é a interface, e sim a instanciação das classes que compartilham a mesma interface mas tem construtores diferentes.

Comment: @Piovezan é muito interessante essa possibilidade que você está apresentando: "Cria-se uma classe e adiciona-se à arquitetura por meio de código novo, e não alterando código já escrito.", mas ainda não percebi como seria feito. Você pode dar o link de um exemplo?

Comment: @Douglas Acredito que os exemplos das respostas [dessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15645/princípio-aberto-fechado-como-entender-isso) demonstrem isso. Pelo menos acredito que seja essa a intenção do princípio.

Comment: @Piovezan essas respostas, na verdade, confirmam o que falei. Veja por exemplo o último parágrafo da resposta do Math, ele está descrevendo exatamente o que fiz aqui. Já a resposta do utluiz só é aplicável quando já se tem as instâncias para serem processadas de maneira uniforme, não trata da criação das instâncias que implementam as interfaces. Sem reflexão, você pode criar uma nova classe implementando/estendendo algo e colocá-la no package, mas seu programa vai tratá-la como se ela nem existisse; por isso será necessário editar algum código "aberto" para "adicioná-la" ao programa.

Comment: @Douglas Acredito que o padrão Fábrica seja um pouco diferente do que você usou em sua resposta, mas tenho pouca experiência com o padrão para dizer. No caso da resposta do utluiz, entendo que ele propõe criar instâncias implementando as interfaces `IntegracaoBanco` e `DadosPagamento` evitando com isso mexer em código existente.

Answer (score 0):

O problema me parece muito simples para termos um factory.

> Estou com um problema na faculdade em engenharia de software que é o
>   seguinte: Tenho o seguinte esquema ao efetuar o pagamento de um
>   carrinho de compras devo saber se é BOLETO ou CARTÃO_DE_CREDITO. Caso
>   seja boleto eu gero um numero aleatório representando o código de
>   barras, caso seja cartão de crédito eu recebo o numero do cartão e a
>   quantidade de parcelas que o cliente desejar e calcular o valor de
>   cada prestação (nesse caso o numero do cartão é alegórico).

Veja minha sugestão:

```
public interface Pagamento {

}

class Boleto implements Pagamento {
    Boleto(valorCompra) { /*construtor*/ }
}

class Cartao implements Pagamento {
    Cartao (valorCompra, numeroCartao, numeroParcelas) { /*construtor*/ }
}
```

E usando:

```
Pagamento pagamento = new Boleto(valorCompra);
Pagamento pagamento = new Cartao(valorCompra, numeroCartao, numeroParcelas);
```

E por você querer algo mais flexível (dinâmico), você poderá estender bem estes comportamentos usando apenas Decorator.

E uma dica: Use `BigDecimal` ao invés de `Double`.